# I want my heading to show Students when not in edit mode and Student when in edit mode how will the syntax look

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my current code but it does not work can someone please provide me with the correct syntax.
editMode is a boolean and it is false on init

```
<h3 *ngIf="!editMode ? 'Students': 'Student'"></h3>
```

Currently it shows nothing at all when I load the page

Comment: Please include your controller/model code as well. This isn't enough information to determine the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*ngIf` takes only a condition and renders the dom element whether it pass.

You should do something like:

```
<h3 *ngIf="editMode">Student</h3>
<h3 *ngIf="!editMode">Students</h3>
```

Alternatively you can use a sort of `else` condition with an ng-template with a reference, something like:

```
<h3 *ngIf="editMode; else notEditMode">Student</h3>
<ng-template #notEditMode>Students</ng-template>
```

You can also use string interpolation to do something like:

```
<h3>{{ editMode ? "Student" : "Students" }}</h3>
```

I would also say that it would be better to remove as much logic as possible from your template and move it to your component class, something like:

```
// your.component.html
<h3>{{ editModeLabel }}</h3>

// your.component.ts
public get editModeLabel() {
  return this.editMode ? "Student" : "Students"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so  much I was looking for the last syntax I forgot how it looked !!

Answer (score 0):

Your h3 tag is empty. You need to populate it.
As the Angular interpolation evaluates a javascript expression, you can use it to populate your html tag with the right content.

```
<h3>{{ !editMode ? 'Students': 'Student' }}</h3>
```